# Prove that if $\lambda$ is an eigenvalue of $f$, then $m_{f}(\lambda)=0$

Tags: linear-algebra

Let $m_f$ be the minimal polynomial of $f$. Let $\lambda$ be an eigenvalue of $f$. Prove that $m_f (\lambda)=0$.

I might be misunderstanding something, but isn't this almost trivial? We know that $m_{f}(f)(v)=0$ from the definition of a minimal polynomial, so wouldn't it be the same if I just put the $\lambda$ instead of the $f$?

Comment: Do you mean $f$ is a matrix? If it is then writing $A$ would be better

Comment: $f$ is an operator.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes it is almost trivial : Since $\lambda$ is an eigenvalue $\exists v \ne 0$ : $f(v) = \lambda v$.

Since $m_{f}(t)$ is the miminal polynomial of the endomorphism is such that $m_{f}(f)(w) = 0 \hspace{0.1cm} \forall w \in V$.

Taking $w = v$, if $m_{f}(t) = a_{n}t^{n} + \cdots + a_{0}$ we have $m_{f}(f) = a_{n}f^{n} + \cdots + a_{0}I_{d}$, so $$0 = m_{f}(f)(v) = a_{n}f^{n}(v) + \cdots + a_{0}v = a_{n} \lambda^{n}v + \cdots + a_{0}v = (a_{n}\lambda^{n}+\cdots+a_{0})v =m_{f}(\lambda)v$$

Since $v$ is an eigenvector $v \ne 0$ hence $m_{f}(\lambda) = 0$.

Comment: This proof works more generally: $p(f)(v)=p(\lambda)v$ for every polynomial $p(t)$.

Answer (score 1):

If $v \in V$ is an eigenvector of $f$ with eigenvalue then $f(v)=\lambda v$ and so $f^k(v)=\lambda^k v$ for all $k \in \mathbb N$. Therefore, by linearity, $p(f)(v)=p(\lambda)v$ for every polynomial $p(t)$. Thus, $p(\lambda)=0$ whenever $p(f)=0$, because $v\ne 0$.